# Detect Close windows event by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

Could you please give me the best way to detect **only window close event** for **all browsers** by jQuery?

I mean clicking <kbd>X</kbd> button on the browser or `window.close()`, not meaning <kbd>F5</kbd>, form submission,
`window.location` or link.
I was looking for many threads but have not found the right way yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There is no specific event for capturing browser close event.

You can only capture on unload of the current page.

By this method, it will be effected while refreshing / navigating the current page.

Even calculating of X Y postion of the mouse event doesn't give you good result.

Answer (score 42):

You can use :

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    //do something
});
```

`Unload()` is deprecated in jQuery version 1.8, so if you use jQuery > 1.8 you can use even beforeunload instead.

The beforeunload event fires whenever the user leaves your page for any reason.

```
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
});
```

Source [Browser window close event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631959/browser-window-close-event)

Comment: Maybe also read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594548/dom-window-unload-event-is-it-reliable

Comment: Hmmm, it means there is no way to detect window close event which working for all browsers?
Thanks for your information.

Comment: best solution its working i have searching and i tried on alot of things but the mos appropriate function which works for me is this one

Comment: does it need to be in a `$(document).ready(function() {})` or can it be outside of that?

Comment: object $(window) is different from $(document), so you can use outside a document-ready statement but if you need to combine this binding with something inside a document, you must use document-ready.

Answer (score 8):

The unload() method was deprecated in jQuery version 1.8.

so if you are using versions older than 1.8

then use -

```
$(window).unload(function(){
alert("Goodbye!");
});
```

and if you are using 1.8 and higher

then use -

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Bye now!";
};
```

hope this will work :-)

Answer (score 6):

There is no specific event for capturing browser close event. But we can detect by the browser positions XY.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).mousemove(function(e) {
    if(e.pageY <= 5)
    {
        //this condition would occur when the user brings their cursor on address bar 
        //do something here 
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Hi there! I edited your post to put all the HTML in code format as it was incorrectly being parsed as HTML tags and not being displayed. In future, pay attention to the preview that shows what your post will look like, as your answer might look significantly different to what you expect!

Answer (score 3):

**Combine the mousemove and window.onbeforeunload event :-**
I used for set TimeOut for Audit Table.

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
 var checkCloseX = 0;
        $(document).mousemove(function (e) {
            if (e.pageY <= 5) {
                checkCloseX = 1;
            }
            else { checkCloseX = 0; }
        });

        window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
            if (event) {
                if (checkCloseX == 1) {

                    //alert('1111');
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "GET",
                        url: "Account/SetAuditHeaderTimeOut",
                        dataType: "json",
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result != null) {
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        };
  });
```

Answer (score 3):

You can solve this problem with vanilla-Js:

### Unload Basics

If you want to prompt or warn your user that they're going to close your page, you need to add code that sets `.returnValue` on a `beforeunload` event:

```
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      event.returnValue = `Are you sure you want to leave?`;
    });
```

There's two things to remember.

1. Most modern browsers (Chrome 51+, Safari 9.1+ etc) will ignore what you say and just present a generic message. This prevents webpage authors from writing egregious messages, e.g., "Closing this tab will make your computer EXPLODE! ".
2. Showing a prompt isn't guaranteed. Just like [playing audio on the web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9JnoKSwh1HU), browsers can ignore your request if a user hasn't interacted with your page. As a user, imagine opening and closing a tab that you never switch to—the background tab should *not* be able to prompt you that it's closing.

### Optionally Show

You can add a simple condition to control whether to prompt your user by checking something within the event handler. This is fairly basic good practice, and could work well if you're just trying to warn a user that they've not finished filling out a single static form. For example:

```
    let formChanged = false;
    myForm.addEventListener('change', () => formChanged = true);
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      if (formChanged) {
        event.returnValue = 'You have unfinished changes!';
      }
    });
```

But if your webpage or webapp is reasonably complex, these kinds of checks can get unwieldy. Sure, you can add more and more checks, but a good abstraction layer can help you and have other benefits—which I'll get to later. ‍♀️

---

### Promises

So, let's build an abstraction layer around the `Promise` object, which represents the *future result* of work- like a response from a network `fetch()`.

The traditional way folks are taught promises is to think of them as a single operation, perhaps requiring several steps- fetch from the server, update the DOM, save to a database. However, by sharing the `Promise`, other code can leverage it to watch when it's finished.

#### Pending Work

Here's an example of keeping track of pending work. By calling `addToPendingWork` with a `Promise`—for example, one returned from `fetch()`—we'll control whether to warn the user that they're going to unload your page.

```
    const pendingOps = new Set();

    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      if (pendingOps.size) {
        event.returnValue = 'There is pending work. Sure you want to leave?';
      }
    });

    function addToPendingWork(promise) {
      pendingOps.add(promise);
      const cleanup = () => pendingOps.delete(promise);
      promise.then(cleanup).catch(cleanup);
    }
```

Now, all you need to do is call `addToPendingWork(p)` on a promise, maybe one returned from `fetch()`. This works well for network operations and such- they naturally return a `Promise` because you're blocked on something outside the webpage's control.

more detail can view in this url:

https://dev.to/chromiumdev/sure-you-want-to-leavebrowser-beforeunload-event-4eg5

Hope that can solve your problem.