# Javascript: Onbeforeunload

Tags: javascript, onbeforeunload

i have the following javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    window.onbeforeunload = function (beforeclose) {

        var message = 'Are you sure that you want to close the greenhouse!!!';
        if (typeof beforeclose == 'undefined') {
            beforeclose = window.event;
        }
        if (beforeclose) {
            beforeclose.returnValue = message;
        }

        return message;
    }
    </script>
```

This method is an alert for the user before closing. What i want is to use a method after closing the window. Like: "When the following page is closed, do something". Is there not something like onafterunload?

Comment: You can't execute anything after closing the window.

Comment: Look this post is the same problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not as after unload is when browser or tab is closed then you can't run. Yes you can handle server side session out event.

Answer (score 0):

No there are not such event available but You can use:

```
$(window).unload(function() {
    //do something
}
```