# How to catch event when web page closed only by button close

Tags: javascript, jquery

Any idea how to catch event when web page closed only by button close:

[image]

Comment: There are no option for this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `beforeunload` event.

Try this sample code

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e)
        {

            e = e || window.event;
            var y = e.pageY || e.clientY;
            if (y < 0){
            return "Do You really Want to Close the window ?"
            }
            else {
            return "Refreshing this page can result in data loss."; 
            }

          }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return "Bye now!";
};
```

Just use simple working code

Answer (score 1):

You cannot detect only that event.

The only way to detect window closing or tab closing ( user want to get out of your website ) is to use the `onbeforeunload` and `onunload` javascript events.

These events are triggered when you go back or when you click a link too, you can check that if you want. Also  `window.showModalDialog()`, `window.alert(),` `window.confirm(),` and `window.prompt(`) can misbehave during this process as you see here [MozillaDeveloper](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload).

Answer (score 1):

There is no specific event for capturing browser close event, but you can use  unload event of the current page.

```
$( window ).unload(function() {
alert( "Bye now!" );
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/unload/

---

Updated:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
      return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});

$(window).on('unload', function(){
      alert("Yes");
});
```