# how to detect only browser close button event in javascript or jquery, No page refresh etc

Tags: javascript, jquery, onbeforeunload, onunload

Kindly help me, how can i detect only browser / tab close button event  in javascript  or jquery. I mean only close button no page refresh and any other menu link opening etc.

I tried this code  on onbeforeunload event of javascript

```js
function handleBrowserCloseButton(event) {

   if(window.event.clientX < 0 && window.event.clientY <0)
    {
      alert('Browser close button clicked');    
    }
}
```

But unfortunately it did not solved my problem. Kindly help me.

Comment: I don't believe this is such an API.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Comment: I dont think you can code such a function!!!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Close windows event by Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

In my understanding, you want to fire a function when the close button of the browser is clicked.

In jQuery:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    console.log("leaving");
    return "sure to leave?";
});
```

In raw javascript:

```
window.onbeforeunload = function (event) {
    console.log("leaving");
    return confirm("sure to leave?");
}
```

However, what kind of code can be executed in the `onbeforeunload` event handler is not very clear:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function () {
    console.log("leaving");
    alert("leaving");
    return "sure to leave?";
});
```

Here, the `console.log` code works, while the `alert` code doesn't.

Comment: this code wil work even if a link is clicked...how to prevent that