# How to implement specific event behaviour for a close(x) button?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a popup in my page.

I want to implement separate functionality for the close(X) button on this popup without affecting the other buttons in this popup.

I already tried the `onunload()` and `onbeforeunload()` events, but they are affecting the other buttons in the popup.

Answer (score 1):

Try this way, for more information check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707413/6105873)

```
 $(window).unload(function() {
    //do something
}
```

Comment: I think you misunderstand my question. I want the functionality for the predefined close(X) button which is at the top-right corner of the window.

Comment: @YallappaBestha I edited the answer, check if it works