# Is there a way to prevent someone from closing a web app?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser

I work in a call center and we use an in-house app for dialing. The app is built using HTML/JavaScript for the front end and MSSQL/Node.js for the back end.

We have a problem where some people close the browser without logging out properly and this is causing data to be lost because the phone call is not being terminated correctly. Is there any way to prevent the user from closing the app using the 'X' button in Chrome?

**I have already setup the generic Chrome message that warns of data loss if the browser is closed, but this isn't really doing the job.**

I am looking for either some kind of JavaScript code to run in the app or perhaps something externally I can run on the local computer. Also, a Chrome startup command line switch would be perfect for the job too, but from my research, I am not sure one exists.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect Close windows event by Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery)

Comment: Not a duplicate. As I said:  I have already setup the generic Chrome message that warns of data loss if the browser is closed, but this isn't really doing the job.

I am looking for something that will PREVENT someone from closing a web app. Not a popup message.

Answer (score 1):

```js
$(window).on("beforeunload", function() { 
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?"); 
})
```

There is no specific event for capturing browser close event.

You can only capture on unload of the current page.

By this method, it will be effected while refreshing / navigating the current page.

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16707249/detect-close-windows-event-by-jquery)

Comment: Thanks for the answer but,  I am looking for something that will prevent someone from closing a web app. Not a popup message. Cheers!