# running some javascript code before when you close a browser tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, onbeforeunload

I'd like to run some javascript whenever someone closes a browser tab but idk how that's possible.

I tried to do what https://stackoverflow.com/a/16707413/569976 described but it's not working for me:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function() {
    return confirm("Do you really want to close?");
});
```

(that's with jquery loaded)

Here's the JS fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/hc9xrgvj/

Any ideas?

Comment: The `beforeunload` event is for the current `window` object (current tab). Are you also attempting to listen to other tabs closing? Are they tabs you [`open()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open)ed or are they unrelated sites/files?

Comment: Also, which browser(s) are you targeting? There are [known consistency issues](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event#usage_notes) with `beforeunload`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event):

> According to the specification, to show the confirmation dialog an
> event handler should call preventDefault() on the event.
>
> However note that not all browsers support this method, and some
> instead require the event handler to implement one of two legacy
> methods:
>
> ```
> assigning a string to the event's returnValue property
> returning a string from the event handler.
> ```
>
> Some browsers used to display the returned string in the confirmation
> dialog, enabling the event handler to display a custom message to the
> user. **However, this is deprecated and no longer supported in most
> browsers**.
>
> To combat unwanted pop-ups, browsers may not display prompts created
> in beforeunload event handlers unless the page has been interacted
> with, or may even not display them at all.
>
> The HTML specification states that calls to window.alert(),
> window.confirm(), and window.prompt() methods may be ignored during
> this event.