# How to call @PreDestroy on browser close event?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

Here is my scenario. I have a component which searches some records and while searching, those records are marked locked. I am using JSF-2 and primefaces. My MBean is ViewScoped. Now i have a requirement, while closing the browser, the lock on those records need to be released. I was searching and my best bet appears to be @PostDestroy. So can someone help, whether using PostDestroy is correct approach. Some of the threads on StackOverFlow suggest, PostDestroy doesn't get called on browser close events. I I am not able to find much on PostDestroy. Can someone provide pointers on this approach?

Thanks,
Ben

Answer (score 0):

Your `@ViewScoped` Bean does not know if the user is closing the browser. For the Bean it does not even matter if the client is a browser or some other HTTP-client.

The lifetime of a `@ViewScoped` Bean ends normally if your application sends a postback to the next view (see [How and when is a view scope bean destroyed in JSF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15265433) for an exact answer).

You can try to detect a closing browser with the JavaScript `window.onunload` event but I would not recommend that. Some browsers fire this event on browser close, others not, some fire it on reload etc. (see [DOM Window unload event, is it reliable?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594548) for more details).

The `@PreDestroy` annotated Method (not @PostDestroy btw.) may also [not be called immediately in some cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930396). You can only rely that it will be called on a session timeout. Which may be a long time for locking records...

You could release the locked records after a shorter period on your own using some kind of scheduler but I'd recommend to switch to [optimistic locking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20930396) (Don't lock and check if data has changed before you write).