# Are there any conditions under which window.unload event does not fire?

Tags: javascript, html, navigator, onunload, sendbeacon

I'm using `navigator.sendBeacon` on the front end to tell the server when a user enters and leaves a page (via `window.load` and `window.unload`). I'm recording the time of arrival/departure server-side. I'm noticing some instances where there is an arrival time but no departure time.

Are there common circumstances, i.e., not a browser/system crash, under which the `window.unload` event fails to fire? Perhaps on redirects, back button, or navigation away from a page before all content has loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No there is no conditions, outside of browser/system crashes, where the window.unload event will fail to fire. It is supported in all major browsers and many previous versions of all major browsers.

[See here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594548/dom-window-unload-event-is-it-reliable).

Answer (score 0):

Seems like unload event is not fired when a tab is discarded by the chrome memory saver. You can manually navigate to chrome://discards and click on "urgent discard" button, you will see that the tab is labled as unloaded, but the event was not fired.

Check [chrome dev blog](https://developer.chrome.com/blog/page-lifecycle-api/#developer-recommendations-for-each-state) for more details